# 'int' object is not subscriptable - not sure how to fix

Tags: python, syntax

hey guys im getting an this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 25, in solveMaze
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 39, in recursiveSolver
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

on this line of code im not sure how to fix any ideas?

```
elif maze.listoflist[currentpos[0][currentpos[1]+1]] == " " and
maze.listoflist[currentpos[0][currentpos[1]+2]] == "*" and [currentpos[0]
[currentpos[1]+2]] not in blacklist:
```

Comment: what is currentpos?  an int? that would explain why it is not subscriptable

Comment: when i index it yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues here, but can only guess unless you share what is in currentpos, and/or maze.listoflist.

Assuming maze.listoflist is a list of list - i.e.: `maze.listoflist = [[...], [...]]`

you need to index this like this:

```
maze.listoflist[index_X][index_Y] // Correct indexing listoflist
```

Not like you have:

```
maze.listoflist[index_X[index_Y]]  // Your version
```

with both index_X and index_Y being integers.

However that is not the error you are seeing.

> 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tells us that you have an int, but are trying to index into it.  subscriptable objects are arrays, tuples, dicts, and strings, or custom objects that implement the **getitem**() interface, and the syntax for indexing into them is to use [ ]

Something you think is a list (or other subscriptable type) is not, it is a int.

Add a print statement before the line throwing the error, and show us the contents of currentpos (it's more likely that than maze.listoflist).

Comment: awsome that really helped and i got past that error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ***currentpos*** is an integer array and you cant subscript (place brackets around) an integer.

Comment: so what would i change because im still not able to figure it out

Comment: In general, you have to come up with another logic to get the maze indices. Is currentpos an integer or integer array? If integer array, try to use currentpos[] not more subscripting/ indexing than that. I cant help you much without further details of code.